# What books describe convolutional neural networks for DSP?

Tags: audio, signal-detection, machine-learning, reference-request

(note: I read the site policy and meta questions about whether such a question is ok.  I will be specific)

I am looking for **books** that specifically cover using convolutional neural networks (CNN) for *audio processing* for signal detection, including the preprocessing steps for the audio and the network architecture. I need direction on preprocessing like the best sample rates, time frames for STFT/spectrograms and image size for a CNN.  Do such books exist?  I couldn't find any on Amazon.

I would also appreciate links to the books on Amazon (or elsewhere) and links to github, if possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge there might not be good books on it already.

I'll assume you have enough background in classical DSP and CNNs ( and NNs in general): go read the papers that things like WaveRNN, torchaudio etc cite.

Papers, not books, because

1. the field might still be too young, so knowledge isn't mature enough to warrant writing a book on it instead of doing forward research in the same time, and
2. your restriction to care about *convolutional* neural networks only might be too impractical to fill a book, but certainly has been investigated in papers.

Comment: I was hoping for at least a chapter in a book as work has been done on it by a number of companies, including Nvidia.  I should read the WaveRNN paper, but I didn't know torchaudio had references, I'll have to check those out,  Thank you!